# How to debug mocha unit tests in a vue application in VSCode?

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, visual-studio-code, mocha.js

I have a **vue application** with unit tests using **unit-mocha**. Tests run fine, but I can't debug them using VSCode debugger.

Here is what I've done:

1. First, I created a vue app in VSCode:

```
vue create hello-world
```

2. Then, I added **unit-mocha**:

```
cd hello-world
vue add unit-mocha
```

This generates file **tests/unit/example.spec.js**:

```
import { expect } from 'chai'
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld.vue'

describe('HelloWorld.vue', () => {
  it('renders props.msg when passed', () => {
    const msg = 'new message'
    const wrapper = shallowMount(HelloWorld, {
      propsData: { msg }
    })
    expect(wrapper.text()).to.include(msg)
  })
})
```

3. I ran the tests:

```
npm run test:unit
```

This works just fine.

But now, I would like to add breakpoints in the file and run the debugger.

So I did the following based on this thread: [Configuration for Debugging Mocha Unit Tests in Vue.js with VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59033696/configuration-for-debugging-mocha-unit-tests-in-vue-js-with-vscode)

4. I switched to **Run tab** on VSCode and clicked **create a launch.json file**:

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Debug Unit Tests",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/bin/vue-cli-service.js",
      "args": ["test:unit", "--inspect-brk", "--watch", "--timeout", "999999"],
      "port": 9229,
      "console": "integratedTerminal"
    }
  ]
}
```

5. I also added **vue.config.js** as suggested in the thread:

```
module.exports = {
  transpileDependencies: ["vuetify"],
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "test") {
      config.merge({
        devtool: "cheap-module-eval-source-map",
      });
    }
  },
};
```

6. Finally I set a breakpoint on the first statement of **example.spec.js**. and clicked **Start debugging** (with "Debug Unit Tests" selected). I have the following output in the terminal console:

```
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:53241/2faf3b6b-dd6f-476a-80bc-51b99df90ec3
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/ad9ccf9a-9e2c-4ed9-a379-3e942c68d185
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
```

Debugger seems to start (even twice??) but the test code isn't executed. My breakpoint is not hit (it turned gray and say "Unbound breakpiont"). Then I stopped the debugger.

I then retried to rerun the tests (`npm run test:unit`) to make sure it's not broken but it's ok.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've finally found the solution I was looking for:

**launch.json** (thanks to [OmegaOdie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7825858/omegaodie)):

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Debug Unit Tests",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "runtimeExecutable": "npx",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "runtimeArgs": ["vue-cli-service", "test:unit", "--inspect-brk"]
    }
  ]
}
```

**vue.config.json** (thanks to [this thread](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/2590)):

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    ...
  },
  // should be false for production
  productionSourceMap: true,
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "test") {
      // if unit testing, keep original lines to make breakpoints in original source files work
      config.merge({
        devtool: "cheap-module-eval-source-map",
      });
    } else {
      // if not unit testing, use normal source maps
      config.merge({
        devtool: "source-map",
      });
    }
  },
};
```

With this configuration, no need of `debugger;` instruction for breakpoints to work.

Comment: Could you not put productionSourceMap in the if statement? So it's on in test and off in prod?

Comment: Yes you are right. I will update my answer.

Comment: Actually no I can't. I get this error: "configuration has an unknown property 'productionSourceMap'".
This property is not part of the "config" object of chainWebPack function.

And it is probably better like that because I really want the source maps while running the application from VS Code (even if not unit testing).

Answer (score 1):

It aint perfect but seems to be working for me, more details can be found @https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/
but the launch.json config should look like this

```
     {
        "name": "TestBreak",
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "runtimeExecutable": "npx",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "runtimeArgs": [
          "vue-cli-service",
          "test:unit",
          "--inspect-brk"
        ],
      }
```

I'm hitting breakpoints with this. However I have to add debugger statements like this

```
debugger; // eslint-disable-line no-debugger
```

The comment is required for me due to some unknown linter.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know the "debugger" command. It may not be the perfect solution but at least I am able to debug my unit tests now.

Comment: After a few more tests and based on your answer, I've finally found a solution without the "debugger;" instruction. Thanks again.